# Progressive matrices with circles and boxes

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

The last question mark should be one of the options to the right.

[image]

This is the 2nd problem I couldn't solve. I do not have the available answers unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is

> [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Go row by row, and you get the the third square from the first two by

> combining every circle that is present in one of the two pictures but not both.

So the answer should be

> [image]

The second one works the same way, but now the combination method is

> Regular addition with the outside being negative compared to the inside

Therefore the answer on the third row will be

> [image]

Comment: Woow incredible, I see it now, thanks for the input!! Never seen that point of view before.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for the first puzzle:

> For each row of the grid, if you combine the first and second images but remove their common circular components (i.e. you take the XOR of the circular components), you get the third image. Notice that the circles can be in one of five spots (the five spots being arranged in an "X" shape).
>  For example, the first row is
>  [image: solution to first row of first puzzle]
>  and the second row is 
>  [image: solution to second row of first puzzle]
>  This means the solution to the third row is
>  [image: solution to third row of first puzzle]
>  which is the top-middle answer.

Comment: That's soo amazing that you showed the solve by painting it, thanks alot for your contribution!! I see it so clearly now!!! Finally I can rest my eyes :D